# Grunt watch stops immediately while converting less to css

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, less, gruntjs

i have a slight problem with grunt, less and file watching. I compile my less code to compressed css code with grunt. My code works fine for just about a minute, then the process won't compile my less file and i have to close terminal on my mac and start the grunt process again. After the break you will find my Gruntfile.js and my Terminal readout.

I hope you can help me :) Thank you for time!
Best regards!

---

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          compress: true,
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
          "assets/css/style.css": "assets/less/style.less"
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      styles: {
        files: ['assets/**/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less:development'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'less:development', 'watch' ]);
};
```

Terminal:

```
Running "less:development" (less) task
File assets/css/style.css created.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...OK
>> File "assets/less/style.less" changed.


Running "less:development" (less) task
File assets/css/style.css created.

Running "watch" task
Completed in 0.012s at Sat Feb 22 2014 23:50:05 GMT+0100 (CET) - Waiting...
OK
>> File "assets/less/style.less" changed.


Running "less:development" (less) task
File assets/css/style.css created.

Running "watch" task
Completed in 0.014s at Sat Feb 22 2014 23:50:21 GMT+0100 (CET) - Waiting...
OK
>> File "assets/less/style.less" changed.


Running "less:development" (less) task
File assets/css/style.css created.

Running "watch" task
Completed in 0.014s at Sat Feb 22 2014 23:50:25 GMT+0100 (CET) - Waiting...
```

Comment: Are you sure your LESS files are valid?

Comment: Yes. I have really easy CSS expressions for testing, like:

body {background-color: #F00;}
and i add or remove:
h1 {color: #00F;}